# Marionette Driver Unreachable exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, firefox-marionette

I am using `Firefox 47.0.1` with `Marionette` driver `geckodriver-v0.8.0-win32`. But I got unreachable browser exception and `firefox` not opening.

My code snippet looks like below :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Desktop/wires-0.6.2-win/wires.exe");
GeckoDriverService service = new GeckoDriverService(new File("C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Desktop/wires-0.6.2-win/wires.exe"), PortProber.findFreePort(), null, null);
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
cap.setCapability("marionette", true);
cap.setCapability("firefox_binary", "G:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe");
driver = new MarionetteDriver(service, cap,PortProber.findFreePort());
```

showing `exception` as :-

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
>   start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure.
>       Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
>       System info: host: 'computer_1', ip: '192.168.1.100', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version:
>   '1.7.0_79'
>       Driver info: driver.version: MarionetteDriver

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for renaming `geckodriver.exe` to `wires.exe`. And usage of GeckoDriverService is not needed. With the stable release they've simplified the coding. Just download [`GeckoDriver`](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and use it like

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    caps.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.BINARY, "G:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver(caps);
```

Comment: thanks for your comment but I am sorry to say that it is not working for me. It is showing me a error like "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed." but it in this path it is exists. After drill down some extent I found that       argsBuilder.add(new Executable(null).getPath()); give the exception in GeckoDriverServiceBuilder class. So could you please give me any suggestion how to resolve this

Comment: Are you sure the firefox installed in `G` or `C` Drive. and post the exact code you used for launching

Comment: yes firefox is on g drive: My new code looks like below:
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Desktop/geckodriver-v0.8.0-win32/geckodriver.exe");
  DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
  cap.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.BINARY, "G:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe");
  driver = new MarionetteDriver(cap);

Comment: uninstall firefox and reinstall and check if it helps

Comment: Do the same thing as you mentioned but still it is not working So I add another line to set the firefox binary e.g System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","G:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox"); now exception changed.org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException:

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'computer_1', ip: '192.168.1.100', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: MarionetteDriver

Comment: It doesn't work for me either and throws error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/jgraham/wires. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/jgraham/wires. I'm using FF48.

Comment: @Jits are you using 32 bit os or 64 bit os. and are you using latest gecko driver

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, you are using selenium 3.0 beta2. Here is the solution:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe"); //change geckodriver path accordingly.
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
webDriver = new MarionetteDriver(capabilities);
```

Please download latest geckodriver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases.