# Selenium FirefoxDriver stopped working after switch to ChromeDriver and back

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I wanted to try Selenium with Chrome so I did changes to my code according to this page https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

**From**:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

**To**:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

It worked fine and after few successful tests I moved it all back to the Firefox driver. But since that moment when I run my test there is a problem. The Firefox window is opened, then there is message that Firefox stopped working and in log I see this error.

**Error**:

`org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.`

I can see in the Firefox url this text `about:blank&utm_content=firstrun` before it crashes.

When I use the ChromeDriver again it works fine with it.

I'm using Windows 10, Firefox 47.0.1.

Comment: Did firefox update in the progress? As of 47.0 you need to enable `marionette`.

Comment: You have to use [MarionetteDriver for this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38005686/3122133) for firefox 47 if you haven't

Comment: Check This ....http://stackoverflow.com/a/37728659/1115090

Comment: I didn't think of that and I guess it is possible that there was some auto update. I will investigate the use of MarionetteDriver and let you know if it worked. Thanks

Comment: look in the task manager if the chrome session is left from the last run..

Comment: Thanks to all the problem was indeed the auto-update of my Firefox between my tests.